# how to make webbrowser in .net use the latest internet explorer

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, browser

Hi I am using Windows Presentation Foundation with .NET in MS Visual Studio 2010 Professional and I am embedding a web page into my application using a WebBrowser object, however it seems that the WebBrowser is using some old version of the Internet Explorer and I really need it to be using the latest Internet Explorer installed on the user's computer.

How to make .NET use the latest Explorer?

Comment: AFAIK , internet explorer if installed on a client machine cannot have multiple versions, which ever is installed it will be the latest one.

Comment: @Furqan: The IE control however, defaults to a safe mode where it acts like IE 7 or so to avoid breaking applications that embed IE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the rendering mode by setting a registry key value for your app.

This may be of some help...

[WebBrowser Control rendering modes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/03/18/webbrowser-control-rendering-modes-in-ie8.aspx)

Comment: thank you, i used <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" > but the problem now is that Explorer is lunching error windows because of jquery, any idea how to deal with this please?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Can you give me more details and I will try help. Otherwise I suggest posting a new question related to these errors.

Comment: javascript errors, i have found a solution on the internet for this, but thank you for help

Comment: can you please link the solution?

Comment: This is the updated version of the article: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version